# Sending data to multiple websocket connections in Python

Tags: python, multithreading, websocket, server

I have a server that gathers data from a bunch of GPS trackers, and want to ship this data out in real time to X connected clients via WebSockets. The trackers connect over TCP (each in their own thread) and send data regularly to the server. The data is merged in a thread called `data_merger` and put in that threads `queue()`. This mechanic works nicely and as intended, however I'm running into issues when I want to send this data to websocket connections.

I tried basing my solution on the [websocket synchronization example](https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/intro.html#synchronization-example), as this seemed like it applied to my usecase. I have a thread called `outbound_worker` that handles the websocket code. From `thread.run()`:

```py
def run(self):
    self.data_merger.name = 'data_merger'
    self.data_merger.start()

    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    start_server = websockets.serve(self.handle_clients, 'localhost', self.port)
    print("WebSocker server started for port %s at %s" % (self.port, datetime.now()))
    loop.run_until_complete(start_server)
    asyncio.get_event_loop().run_forever()
```

Then the handler method for the websocket server:

```py
async def handle_clients(self, websocket, path):
    while True:
        try:
            # Register the websocket to connected set
            await self.register(websocket)
            data = self.data_merger.queue.get()
            await send_to_clients(data)
            await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        except websockets.ConnectionClosed:
            print("Connection closed")
            await self.unregister(websocket)
            break

async def send_to_clients(self, data):
    data = json.dumps(data)
    if self.connected:
        await asyncio.wait([ws.send(data) for ws in self.connected])
```

The `register()` and `unregister()` methods are identical to the example I linked above. The client I'm using is a basic loop that prints the data received:

```py
async def hello():
    uri = "ws://localhost:64000"
    while True:
        async with websockets.connect(uri) as websocket:
            print("Awaiting data...")
            data = await websocket.recv()
            
            #print(f"{data}")
            print(f"{json.loads(data)}")


asyncio.get_event_loop().run_until_complete(hello())
```

As I am new to asynchronous calls in Python and websockets in general, I'm not sure if my approach is correct here. Since I am trying to push data right after registering a new connection, the code seems to halt at the `await send_to_clients(data)` line. Should I rather handle this in the `data_merger` thread and pass the `connected` set?

Another issue is that if I simply use the `client_handler` to `register()` and `unregister()` the new connections, it seems to just loop over the `register()` part and I'm unable to connect a second client.

I guess my questions can be condensed into the following:

- How do I accept and manage multiple open connections over websocket, similar to a multithreaded socket server?
- Is there a way to trigger a function call (for instance `register()` *only* on new websocket connections, similar to `socket.listen()` and `socket.accept()`?

Comment: You should probably look into "message brokers" and the pub/sub (publish / subscribe) patterns. Not only are you duplicating a lot of existing work, you're also doing it in a way that is suboptimal, so you will be faced with scaling concerns as your infrastructure grows.

Comment: Thanks, I basically just need a pointer in the right direction. I'll check that out